# React Native Bluetooth Classic Reading Issue

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, read-data

I am attempting to read the response after sending a command to the IoT device. I have verified that the command I'm sending is correct, and the IoT device does send a response, as I've confirmed using the Bluetooth Serial App available on the Play Store. However, I am encountering difficulties in reading the response within my application. Please advise on how to troubleshoot this issue.

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIke5.png)

I was expecting to read the response from the IoT device.

Comment: What does your log say? Does it contain the read value?

Comment: Is onDataReceived ever called?

Comment: It is also unclear which react-native library you are using to connect to a bluetooth classic device

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan, I am using react-native-bluetooth-classic. onDataReceived is never called. If I try to read the device, it gives me 0 as a response.